# How to show an Expandable Layout over a Frame Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on my app layout. Currently, I am showing a map in the FrameLayout.I am trying to show another layout over the map window and make it expandable or drag-gable smoothly. I tried placing another frame layout below the current frame layout. It displays the layout but it is not giving the desired effect. I need something like this image

[image]

This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout

android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorblock"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/homelist"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/list"
        android:tint="@color/white"/>

    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homelist"
        android:background="@color/button_material_light"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <com.example.myapp.custompalette.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_driverstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/offline"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:font="@string/font_UBERMedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homelist"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        style="@style/SwitchCompatStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch_driverstatus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <com.example.myapp.custompalette.FontTextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/ub__red"
        android:id="@+id/txt_checkdriverstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkstatus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:font="@string/font_UBERMedium"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iv_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorblock"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttom sheet is what you are looking for, you can see examples [here](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) , and [here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427)